# How to know if a running background process crashed?

Tags: c, linux, shell, coredump

I have a process `myprocess` that I run from the script. Is it possible to check if this process executed successfully or crashed?

This is what my script looks like:

```
myprocess 12 &
sleep 12
# I want to check here if the process crashed
```

The reason why I am running the process in the background is simple. I want to do other tasks before `sleep`ing. After I wake up, I want to see if the process exited gracefully or if it crashed (dumped core).

PS: Please comment below if any other details or more code is required.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: You can't arbitrarily assume that kernel is allowing core dumps. The kernel parameter `fs.suid_dumpable` allows/disallows core dumps. In most RHEL 6.8+ derivates, this is set to disallow. You also need to find where the core dump is placed. The default is in the `pwd` but it can be configured to dump elsewhere and with a different name pattern. This is set in `kernel.core_pattern`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you **DON'T HAVE** a file named `core` on your `$PWD` (otherwise it will be removed), this is the **lazy** way to do it:

(Note that **this** [the *lazy* core file approach **only**] assumes the correct parametrization of sysctl `fs.suid_dumpable` if `myprocess` will have its [privilege levels changed or is execute only](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt). Also note that `kernel.core_pattern` settings may cause the core file to be dumped somewhere else and not at `$PWD`. See [this article](https://tobyheywood.com/kernel-tuning-kernel-core_pattern/) in order to properly set it. Thanks to @alvits for pointing out these two potential issues. Anyway, **I don't really recommend the usage of the following core file approach**.)

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f core
ulimit -c unlimited

myprocess 12 &

# ... Do your stuff ...

sleep 12

if [ -f core ]; then
    echo "This is a minimal example to show that the program dumped core."
fi
```

Also note that this only works if meanwhile nothing else dumps a core to `$PWD`

A **cleaner** approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

(rm -f /tmp/myprocess.success && myprocess 12 && touch /tmp/myprocess.success) &

# ... Do your stuff ...

sleep 12

if [ -f /tmp/myprocess.success ]; then
    echo "myprocess returned EXIT_SUCCESS. But if it didn't returned before sleep 12 elapsed, this will fail."
fi
```

The **correct** way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

myprocess &

# Store myprocess PID
MYPROCESS_PID="$!"

# ... Do your stuff here ....

# Wait until myprocess returns
wait "${MYPROCESS_PID}"

# Store myprocess exit status (returned by wait)
$ret="$?"

if [ "${ret}" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Myprocess didn't exited with EXIT_SUCCESS"
fi
```

Comment: You might want to add a note that the first solution relies on `fs.suid_dumpable` for applications with setuid, which is usually turned off and `kernel.core_pattern` which determines the location and name pattern of the core. The OP and future readers may get disappointed if it doesn't work in their environment.

Comment: Sure, although I don't really recommend to use the first approach in any situation like this. But will update. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, as far as I know, fs.suid_dumpable only affects setuid binaries, which I don't believe it's the OP case.

Comment: `$ret=` is not valid code; it should just be `ret=`. And consider putting the assignment on the same line as the `wait` (`wait "$myprocess_pid"; myprocess_rc=$?`) -- that way people don't add new commands between the two lines and break the association between them.

Comment: Same applies to `myprocess & myprocess_pid=$!` being a safer practice, making it harder for future edits to inadvertently change `$!` before it gets assigned. (Use of lowercase variable names in my examples is per https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, btw -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system, others are reserved for application use; since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, the convention applies to both classes).